# Is there any way to recognize the last kafka message of every partition in multi partition topic and multiple consumers apart from lag?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-topic

Is there any way to recognize the last kafka message of every partition in multi-partitioned topic and multiple consumers apart from lag?

I know one way to identify the last message which is through AdminClient API/ kafka consumer API. But need to use different method.

Comment: Why do you need different method? What are you requirements?

Comment: I need to check programatically and not using CLI tool.

Comment: Everything you can do from the CLI you can do it from code with Kafka Java API or even some other libraries.

Comment: Can you please tell some libraries? I need to integrate in scala project.

Answer (score 0):

The only ways are to query the end offset of the partitions using admin/consumer, as you've found.

You could install Confluent REST Proxy and use HTTP calls, maybe, or use shell scripts, and parse the output, but it's just an abstraction over the same methods